# UIScrollView cuts labels off

Tags: objective-c

I have a `UIScrollView` and numerous `labels` embedded in it. However, if the bottom `labels`' text is longer than usual, the text is being cut off, that is, the `UIScrollView` won't let me scroll...

How can I fix it?

EDIT: right, sorry...

The labels are created programmatically using the following:

```
UILabel *parametersLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,previousLabelFrameOriginY + previousLabelFrameSizeHeight + 10,self.view.frame.size.width - 10,20)];
parametersLabel.text = self.parameters;
parametersLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[parametersLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HoeflerText-Regular" size:16]];
parametersLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[parametersLabel sizeToFit];
[self.scrollView addSubview:parametersLabel];
```

I have not programmed UIScrollView - it has the default settings that the Storyboard assigns to it.

[image: The text on the bottom is cut off and I can't scroll it.]

Comment: put some codes there, especially for you labels and UIScrollView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the `contentSize` of your scroll view based on heights and postions of your labels.

For example:

```
CGFloat scrollHeight = 0.0f;
for (UIView* view in scrollView.subviews)
{
   scrollHeight += view.frame.size.height;
}

[scrollView setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(320, scrollHeight))];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `contentSize` property of your scroll view.  If you simply want to make the `contentSize` large enough to contain all of the subviews of the scroll view, try this:

```
CGSize size = CGSizeZero;
for (UIView *view in self.scrollView.subviews) {
    CGRect frame = view.frame;
    size.width = MAX(size.width, CGRectGetMaxX(frame));
    size.height = MAX(size.height, CGRectGetMaxY(frame));
}
self.scrollView.contentSize = size;
```